# Presentation for a Finite Etale Cover of an (Affine) Elliptic Curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

I posted this question on MSE a few days ago, but I did not get much interest in it. So I thought I would try my luck here. If you are interested in answering the question, there is a bounty over on MSE.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911318/presentation-for-a-finite-etale-cover-of-an-affine-elliptic-curve

---

I will write the question first, then try and explain myself more clearly after:

**Question:** How can one find a *presentation* for a finite etale cover of an *affine piece* of an elliptic curve?

If $E/\mathbb{C}$ is an elliptic curve, then it is homeomorphic to a torus. For this reason we know $\pi_{1}(E) \cong \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$. If we puncture $E/\mathbb{C}$, then we obtain an affine curve, let us denote it $X$. Moreover, $X$ can be thought of as the elliptic curve minus the point at infinity. Since this is affine, we can give a presentation for it, say, 
$$X:= \text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle y^{2} - f(x) \rangle)$$
for $f(x) = x(x-1)(x-2)$.

We know $\pi_{1}^{et}(X) \cong \hat{\pi}_{1}(X(\mathbb{C})^{an})$ and $X(\mathbb{C})^{an}$ is homeomorphic to a punctured torus. The fundamental group of a punctured torus is the free group on two generators $F_{2}$. The profinite completion of which is non-trivial. So, there are *algebraic covers* of such an affine curve. How can we get our hands on them? Is there a presentation which in some sense is in terms of $f(x)$? Does anyone have a reference for a discussion on such a construction?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in this situation any etale cover will be a smooth algebraic curve $C$ and this curve has to be affine. Now the cover extends to a covering $\overline{C} \to E$, it may be ramified but only above $0$. Now you can use the Riemann-Hurwitz formula to get some necessary conditions for such a cover to exist.

Comment: In fact, you're seeking for the analogue of the theory of "dessins d'enfants" for punctured elliptic curves. I think this is difficult and I'm not aware of any explicit general result. The étale covers of $E$ are easy to describe: they are given by isogenies and explicit equations can be computed using Vélu's formulas. On the other hand the universal cover of $E-\{0\}$ is isomorphic to the upper-half plane $\mathcal{H}$, so $E-\{0\}=\mathcal{H}/\Gamma$  for some discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, but to my knowledge no one knows how to compute it.

Comment: I expect this is just as difficult as computing equations for covers of $\mathbb{P}^1 - \{0,1,\infty\}$. To get a sense of the difficulties involved in the latter problem, you might be interested in [this article by Sijsling and Voight](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2529.pdf)

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault There is at least one punctured elliptic curve for which the discrete subgroup of $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is "easy" to compute - it is the commutator subgroup of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, which is a torsion-free congruence subgroup of index 12, level 6, a single cusp, and with $j$-invariant 0.

Comment: @WillChen That's interesting! I was indeed looking for a modular curve of genus 1 with a single cusp but thought there was none. Are there other examples among finite index subgroups of SL_2(Z)?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Sorry for the late reply, but two references for your question are given on the second page (Rhodes + Petersson) in this interesting article: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2008-136-07/S0002-9939-08-09262-9/S0002-9939-08-09262-9.pdf

Answer (score 4):

If you are just looking for examples you can consider the following construction, which is geometric although I don't care to write down the equations explicitly.

Recall, that if $C$ is a compact Riemann surface and $F$ is a reduced divisor of degree $f$ then there is a *$f$-fold cyclic cover of $C$, branched at $F$*, which we denote by $D$. That is, there is a degree $f$ map:
$$
\pi\colon D \rightarrow C
$$
which has branching of order $f$ at each of the points of $F$. (Remark: this cover depends on a choice of $f$-th tensor root of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_C(E)$. There are always $f$-th roots as the map:
$$
(-)^{\otimes f}\colon\mathrm{Pic}_1(C) \rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}_f(C)
$$
is surjective.)

Using this we can construct the following étale covers of the punctured torus. Start by considering an étale $d$-sheeted cover of your elliptic curve $E$:
$$
\phi\colon C \rightarrow E.
$$
(Thus, $C$ is a genus 1 curve as well.) Let $x\in E$ be a point and consider a reduced divisor of degree $f$, $F\subset\phi^{-1}(x)$, which is supported on the preimage of $x$ in $C$. Taking the cyclic cover branched at $F$ we get:
$$
D\xrightarrow{\pi}C\xrightarrow{\phi}E.
$$
Then the composition $\phi\circ \pi$ is a degree $d\cdot f$ map which is étale away from the point $x\in E$.